# How to fill a list with N elements from 1 to N accepting repetition in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I want to create a predicate **fill_list/2** to fill a list with numbers from 1 to N for Example if my query is

```
fill_list(3,X).
```

which N is 3 and X is the list, I want X to be like these examples:

```
X = [1 , 1 , 1];
X = [1, 2 , 2];
X = [3 , 1 ,2];
```

There's no constrants just the numbers be values from 1 to N

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used permutations but it can't create repetition

Comment: `fill_list(N, L) :- length(L, N), maplist(between(1,N), L).`

Comment: It's working please add it as an answer 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fill_list(N, L) :- length(L, N), maplist(between(1,N), L).
```

The idea here is to make the list of the specified length, and then specify that all the members are in the desired range of 1-N. I think this is a nice demonstration of how closely the Prolog can match the problem specification.